# IOS 13 crashing when converting video to MP4 and different resolution

Tags: ios, xamarin, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

Since the rollout of IOS 13, I am unable to convert MP4 files into different resolutions.  It's using the standard AVFoundation library on Xamarin.IOS 13.

Any ideas why the app would crash out when the conversion is about to take place?

Xamarin Simulator IOS 13 works no problem. This only happens when rolling out to test.

```
AVAssetExportSession export = new AVAssetExportSession(asset, AVAssetExportSession.Preset640x480);

    export.OutputUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(to); 
    export.OutputFileType = AVFileType.Mpeg4;
    export.ShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;

    bool exportComplete = false;

    export.ExportAsynchronously(() =>
    {

        if (export.Error != null)
            Console.WriteLine(export.Error.LocalizedDescription);  
        else
        {
            asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(export.OutputUrl);
            foreach (var track in asset.Tracks)
            {
                if (track.NaturalSize.Height > 0)
                {
                    var size = track.NaturalSize;
                    Debug.WriteLine("New size: " + size.Width + "x" + size.Height);
                    break;
                }
            }

            fileLength = new FileInfo(to).Length;
            Debug.WriteLine("New: " + fileLength);
       }

       exportComplete = true;

   });
```

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information: abort() called

Comment: It may be helpful to get the device log output when the crash occurs. If the issue occurs when debugging locally to an iOS device, you can view/collect device logs from the Device Logs panel in Visual Studio. See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/enhanced-device-logging-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Thanks for that, I will give that a go.

Comment: You can share the log here and we can check for you.